# Rails - Ajax call controller action and redirect to another controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm building an rails app and I want to create a loading page and then get the location of the user in the loading page and pass it to the next page. What I'm doing right now is :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        $.ajax("/welcome/send")
    }
</script>
<body onload="getLocation()"></body>
```

so I call the action send in the controller welcome using ajax and this is in the welcome controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  require 'barometer'

  def index
  end

  def send 
    redirect_to(:controller => 'top', :action => 'index')
  end
end
```

I want to test it if I can really call the action and redirect it to another page or not but it doesn't work. I also already add the top controller to the routes and I can access it directly.

Is there anybody here know how to properly do this? I also will hear any other idea about how to achieve the main goal (to get the location of the user using geolocation and pass it to controller)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just redirect to the route that TopController index has? Something like: `redirect_to tops_path` or `redirect_to "{the path of tops index}"` as a string.

Comment: @Omni Thanks for your advice, but it's still failed. How can I check if the send action is properly called or not? Thanks!

Comment: What I tend to do to see if actions are running is by putting a `puts` statement in the action. If the action is running, it should turn up in the server output.

Comment: @Omni and yes it is called. DO you have any idea?

Comment: Well at the moment all it's doing is the AJAX call is hitting that method, which is only going to redirect a user. The redirect doesn't pass any data to the action it is redirecting to. I'm not sure how to deal with this case specifically in an efficient way.

Comment: @Omni yes actually I want to pass latitude and longitude the the action that I want to redirect. But for now I just want to check is it possible or not. Do you know other way to do this?

Comment: All you'd have to do is assign the lat and long to a variable and pass that variable as a param to the new action. Something similar to `redirect_to <path>, :location_data => <variable>`. How  you should do that, I don't know but it is definitely possible.

Comment: why are you redirecting in an Ajax request? It does not work that way. If you just want to call 'top/index', why dont you create a route for that and call that in the ajax call, instead of going to `send` method and redirecting from there.

If you are intending to load the 'top/index' page again, after the ajax request, you can use `success` block of `$.ajax` like this:
    $.ajax({url: '/welcome/send', success: function(result) { window.location = '/top/index' } })